# Problem with FirestoreRecyclerAdapter when putting putExtra to a New Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I go to the experts for the following problem, the code used works perfectly, it brings me the list from the cloud Firebase, the recuclervieqw works perfect, the problem is that I wish that when clicking any item on the list, I open a new activity, and I need to go through Putextra data to show in it, but I do not know how to code that part, if someone helps me I would appreciate it very much.

Here all the code used:

--------------- Fragment Layout -------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivosFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_id">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

----------- Listadoactivos Layout ---------------

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/contenedor">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagenprincipal"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/fondopersonajes1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titulo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:maxLength="40"
                    android:text="@string/selecciona_una_noticia"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp" />


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="#f6ce3d"> </View>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

-------------- Model: masvotados.java ----------------

```
public class masvotados {

    private String titulo;
    private String descripcion;
    private String imagen1;

    public masvotados() {

    }

    public masvotados(String titulo, String descripcion, String imagen1) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.imagen1 = imagen1;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getImagen1() {
        return imagen1;
    }

    public void setImagen1(String imagen1) {
        this.imagen1 = imagen1;
    }
}
```

------------------- MasvotingFragment.java ----------------------

```
public class MasvotingFragment extends Fragment {

    public MasvotingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private FirebaseFirestore mDatabase;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView ;
    private RecyclerViewMasvotados mAdapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_masvoting, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        basedatocall();

    }

    private void basedatocall() {

        Query query = mDatabase.collection("Campeonatos");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<masvotados> firestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<masvotados>()
                .setQuery(query, masvotados.class).build();

        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMasvotados(firestoreRecyclerOptions);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAdapter !=null){
            mAdapter.stopListening();
        }

    }
}
```

---------------- Adapter: RecyclerViewMasvotados.java ------------------

```
public class RecyclerViewMasvotados extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<masvotados, RecyclerViewMasvotados.ViewHolder>  {

    private Context mContext;
    private RequestOptions options;

    /**
     * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See {@link
     * FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public RecyclerViewMasvotados(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<masvotados> options) {
        super(options);

        this.options = new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.fondopersonajes)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewMasvotados.ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull masvotados model) {

        holder.titulo.setText(model.getTitulo());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(model.getImagen1()).apply(options).into(holder.imagenprincipal);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewMasvotados.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listadomasvotados, parent, false);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        viewHolder.view_contenedor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), Campeonatos.class);

                //intent.putExtra("titulo");
                //intent.putExtra("descripcion");


                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView titulo;
        LinearLayout view_contenedor;
        CircleImageView imagenprincipal;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mContext = itemView.getContext();
            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
            imagenprincipal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenprincipal);
            view_contenedor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contenedor);
        }
    }
}
```

As Additional data I am using the Firebase UI Library, therefore I am using the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

That detail is that it has made me not know how to obtain the data through the Putextra, I hope you can help me. Beforehand thank you very much

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **more than 250 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create a putextra without errors using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, and it is as simple as this:

intent.putExtra ("titulo", getItem (viewholder.getAdapterPosition ()). getTitulo ());